# Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using arrays in a closure

Tags: swift, closures

Consider the following toy example Swift code:

```
protocol Testable{}
class MyObj : Testable{}

class Test {

    var arr:[Testable] = []
    var didRun:Bool = false

    func run() -> [Testable]{
        if(didRun){
            println("arr has \(arr.count) elements")
            for e in arr{  // following access causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
                println(e)
            }

            return arr
        } else{
            provider({ (myArr : [AnyObject]) -> () in
                self.arr = myArr as [MyObj]
                self.didRun = true
                })
            return []
        }
    }

    func provider( cb : ([AnyObject] -> ()) ){
        let a:[MyObj] = [MyObj(),MyObj(),MyObj()]
        cb(a)
    }
}
```

and calling it the following way:

```
 let t = Test()
 t.run()
 t.run()
```

This compiles but crashes at runtime when trying to iterate over the returned array. The `arr.count` is also garbage, returns a random big number such as `232521760` and `arr` itself points to somewhere far away around `0xfffffff9`, meaning clearly it's garbage.

My question is why is this? Compiler does not complain about type errors. Why am I not able to use the `myArr` array, does the compiler make `myArr` de-allocated after leaving the closure?

I can fix by changing the `provider` call to be:

```
provider({ (myArr : [AnyObject]) -> () in
    for e in myArr{
      self.arr.append(e as MyObj)
    }
    self.didRun = true
 })
```

but I'm more interested in why my first code does not work.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me closure semantics in Swift and why the above produces such errors.

Comment: If you remove the downcast (i.e. change your code so `self.arr = myArr as [MyObj]` becomes `self.arr = myArr`), the code works. No idea why, been working on it for an hour... I'll come back when I have something.

Comment: If it helps, I can narrow it down to a much smaller example: https://gist.github.com/gothick/4f08e7ecfe35a5e54cdb . As @akashivskyy says, if you lose the cast to [MyObj], it works. Not sure why.

Comment: @MattGibson Or even simpler: https://gist.github.com/akashivskyy/4dfc6ca736f5ff6fb222. This only happens if the outer array variable has a protocol type.

Comment: @akashivskyy Yeah, I'd clocked that, too. This very much feels like an actual bug, right?

Comment: @MattGibson Yeah, take a look at the updated gist: https://gist.github.com/akashivskyy/4dfc6ca736f5ff6fb222. It even crashes without a clousure.

Comment: @MattGibson What's strange here, is the fact that this is just a basic downcasting operation. If it really is a bug, it is a severe one. It's strange for me that it hasn't yet been eliminated by the 4th beta. Or... maybe it isn't a bug? I asked a question at ADF: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/238922. You can follow it if you want, maybe an Apple enineer will shed some light.

Comment: @akashivskyy Following, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** as noted by [@SevenTenEleven](https://devforums.apple.com/people/SevenTenEleven) (an Apple employee) on the [ADF thread related to this question](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1016118#1016118):

> It looks like there are issues with some covariant array assignments; please file a bug so we can either properly ban them at compile-time or properly implement them at runtime.

Let's do this, **[I did](http://openradar.appspot.com/17894354)**.

---

After doing some [experiments](https://gist.github.com/akashivskyy/4dfc6ca736f5ff6fb222) and [research](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/238922), I came to the following conclusions:

- This has nothing to do with clousures and outer scopes
- The error happens only if you downcast `[AnyObject]` to `[MyObj]`
- The error hapens only if the "outer" variable is declared as an array of protocol types

Since it seems like `provider` would always return `Testable`, I was able to get your code working by changing your `provider` function declaration and explicitly marking `a` variable as an array of `Testable`:

```
func provider(cb: [Testable] -> ()) {
    let a : [Testable] = [MyObj(), MyObj(), MyObj()]
    cb(a)
}
```

Then there's no need to downcast, so there's no error. Here's the whole code:

```
protocol Testable {}
class MyObj : Testable {}

class Test {
    var arr : [Testable] = []
    var didRun = false
    func run() -> [Testable] {
        if didRun {
            println("arr has \(arr.count) elements")
            for e in arr {
                println(e)
            }
            return arr
        } else {
            provider() { (myArr : [Testable]) in
                self.arr = myArr
                self.didRun = true
            }
            return []
        }
    }
    func provider(cb: [Testable] -> ()) {
        let a : [Testable] = [MyObj(), MyObj(), MyObj()]
        cb(a)
    }
}

let t = Test()
t.run()
t.run()
```

The preceeding code outputs:

```
arr has 3 elements
_TtC5hgfds5MyObj
_TtC5hgfds5MyObj
_TtC5hgfds5MyObj
```

Comment: Thanks for getting to the bottom of this, the thread on apple dev forum is informative!

Comment: No problem, challenges like that are the best way to learn some more advanced aspects of a language. I edited the answer by including a quote of the SevenTenEleven's reply from the forums.

Comment: I get the error when I am appending array, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems swift doesn't like for-in loops on arrays of AnyObject or protocols. However, if you change it to an old-fashioned for-i loop, things work just fine.

So instead of:

```
for e in arr { // causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Just write:

```
for var i = 0; i < arr.count; ++i { // works fine
    let e = arr[i]
    ...
}
```

Comment: yep, that would seem to be the case, certainly with an Array of closures. At least as of Xcode 6.3 (6D520o)

Comment: have been informed that this has since been fixed although I've yet to try it